# What are the correct steps of integrating with a Dirac delta function of two variables that you're integrating over?

Tags: calculus, dirac-delta

I have the following function where $F(x)$ is a normal distribution and in this context it represents a 'weight':
$$R(t) = \int_\tau \int_x T(\tau)\cdot F(x) \cdot \delta(t -(mx+b) - \tau) \: dx \: d\tau$$

I cannot isolate $F(x)$ and integrate it to 1 since the $(mx+b)$ is inside of the dirac delta function. They are interdependent. I originally tried isolating the $F(x)$ and integrated it to 1 then I solved for the following:
$$= \int_\tau T(\tau) \cdot \delta(t -(mx+b) - \tau) \: d\tau \int_x \: F(x)dx $$
$$=\int_\tau T(\tau) \cdot \delta(t -(mx+b) - \tau) \: d\tau$$
$$  =T((mx+b) - t) $$

I checked this in Mathematica and got the same result, but I took the wrong steps to get there. What would've been the correct steps instead of trying to isolate $F(x)?$

Comment: The Dirac Delta is NOT a function and one does not integrate a Dirac Delta.

Comment: @MarkViola Ah yes, sorry. I've edited the original question. Thanks!

Comment: Choose one variable to integrate out first, e.g. $\tau$, giving $R=\int_xT(mx+b-t)F(x)dx$.

Comment: @J.G. So treat this like any other iterated integral where $T(\tau)$ just integrates to 1, then after integrating over x, go back and integrate of $T(\tau)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what is wrong in your case is only the fact in your second equation, you cannot write the $x$ integral after the Dirac as it is depending on $x$. But you can write for example
$$
\iint T(\tau)\,F(x)\,\delta(t-mx-b-\tau)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d τ = \int F(x) \left(\int T(\tau)\,\delta(t-mx-b-\tau)\,\mathrm d τ\right)\mathrm d x
\\
= \int F(x)\, T(t-mx-b)\,\mathrm d x
$$
using the definition of the Dirac delta as a measure in the $\tau$ variable. This is now an integral that depends on your specific $F$ and $T$. In general, you cannot simplify it much further. If $F$ is a Gaussian, then you can expand the square in the Gaussian to factorize the $t-b$ part.

*Remark:* the last integral can be written as a convolution. If $T_m(x) = T(mx)$ then
$$
\int F(x)\, T(t-mx-b)\,\mathrm d x = \int F(x)\, T_m(\tfrac{t-b}{m}-x)\,\mathrm d x = (F * T_m)(\tfrac{t-b}{m})
$$

Comment: This was a nice way of simplifying it, but mathematical was able to break it down further to $T(b-mx+t)$. Is it possible to get to this step with your simplification?

Comment: Also you would say the dirac is a measure in both the $\tau$ and $F$ variable in this case right?

Comment: The Dirac can be seen as a variable in the $\tau$ or in the $x$ variable. No, this is not possible to simplify it further, in particular this is not a function of $x$ (the $x$ is a dummy variable in the integral). I suppose Mathematica did an error or your code in Mathematica is different from the question.

Comment: If I were to think of the function $R(t)$ as $R(t; x)$; thinking of x as a parameter then I can simplify it further right?

Comment: Hmm perhaps replace $mx$ by $m*x$ ? No, the function $R$ does not depend on $x$. Like $\int_0^1 x\,\mathrm d x = 1/2$ does not depend on $x$.

Comment: Ah you're right. The $mx$ was the issue and should've been $m*x$ The only way this can simplify is if I explicitly express $T$; eg. if $T$ is a sin function it would be something like $sin (t-m \cdot x - b)$